# better way to set alpha for a view after a few seconds in apple watch / watchkit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview, apple-watch

I am trying to set alpha with animation to image view in swift for apple watch application.

to do that i have tried code below

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
        self.splashscreenImage.alpha = 1.0
        return
   })
```

but its iving error as

```
  'WKInterfaceImage' does not have a member named 'alpha'
```

so i implemented code below in willActivate function

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: Selector("splashscreenAlpha"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

and

```
func splashscreenAlpha() {
   self.splashscreenImage.setAlpha(0.0)
}
```

but in this scenario, view is like invisible, like image view has a black background. But i would like it to gone with animation. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using

`UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
        self.splashscreenImage.setAlpha(1.0)
        return
   })`

to make alpha animation.